# Help with Buoyancy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, buoyancy, fluid-statics

An object floats in both water and oil. Oil is less dense than water. While floating, the object displaces a larger volume of oil than water. why is the buoyant force the same in each liquid ?

Comment: The wording makes this feel like a homework question, which we're not here to do. What have you found by searching so far?

Comment: When an object floats, the buoyant force= weight of the body, which is a constant ( here)

Answer (score 1):

When an object floats, it is in static equilibrium.  The vertical forces on it - its weight downwards, and the buoyancy force upwards - are balanced.  The weight of the object is the same in both cases, so the buoyancy force must also be the same.

This may not seem to be the case : it may seem that the buoyancy force is weaker when the object floats with a larger fraction below the surface.  However, the larger fraction below the surface compensates for the fact that the liquid is less dense.

In accordance with Archimedes' Principle, the buoyancy force is the weight of fluid displaced by the object.  The same weight of liquid is displaced in both cases.  A greater volume of oil is displaced to make up for its lower density.

Answer (score -2):

Because oil is less dense more will be displaced to compensate the weight of the object and reach equilibrium.